# How to build java project with command-line arguments in IntelliJ

Tags: java, build, compilation, intellij-idea, javac

I have a java test project which has two binary fields.when I want to compile the project in IntelliJ,it complains that I should use -source 7 instead of -source 1.6 while compiling.my JDK is the latest.I don't know how to fix this.

sample code:

```
public class BitWiseTest {
    static int val1 = 0b01110;//compile-time error
    static int val2 = 0b11011;//compile-time error
    public static void main()
    {
        System.out.println(val1 & val2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have the *language level* of the project set to 1.6 - this is a setting independent (-ish) of what version JDK you use.

Comment: Go to File->Project Structure->Project & Change the project language level to 7.0 & project SDK to 1.7

Comment: yes, you should be able to set which jdk you're using inside the IDE

Comment: @Extreme Coders, you were right.provide an answer to get reputation if you want.

Comment: @raminomrani All right, thanks for the gesture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue mainly happens due to incorrect configuration of Project language level set. Thus although you may be using java 7 but since the project language level is configured incorrectly it uses constructs only valid in that language level.Thus you get the error.
To fix it follow the steps :

Go to File->Project Structure->Project & Change the project language level to 7.0 & project SDK to 1.7